# Having trouble with boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, menu

Hey i'm having trouble booting to Ubuntu. Please bear with me it's my first time posting here.

I was going through a couple of tutorials on speeding up your system and edited one of the values in the grub file located /etc/default/grub

Now the GRUB_TIMEOUT is set to '0' and when I start up my laptop it goes to the default os boot menu which is Ubuntu. But it boots to Windows instead of Ubuntu which makes it very difficult to fix from Windows.

I have downloaded ext2explore to change the value which I can do but I can't update the grub so it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Ubuntu from a DVD or USB and use the program "Boot-Repair". That should fix the GRUB for you.

Comment: I have a boot disk with ubuntu on it. Should I use that?

Comment: Boot from it, and select "try ubuntu". When it starts run the program.

Comment: How did it go? :)

Comment: Well... I'm in try ubuntu now and im going to get boot repair now

Comment: Were do i get boot-repair?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/292783/21195

Comment: Should be ready for use all ready?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

Comment: Got it... little loadie thing is doing is business now

Comment: im going to reboot now

Comment: Good..Hope it works :)

Comment: IT WORkS :D your a life saver... thanks a ton, also for walking me threw it all :D

Comment: No problem! :D Happy to help!

Comment: Btw, make the answer green :P