# Full disk but it isn't

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

[image: df -h show me the disk isn't full]

[image: GParted show me the disk is full]
I am trying to understand why on GParted `sda1` look like full (and therefore it's impossible to edit the partition) but on terminal show me the disk in use is just 9%.
Can anyone help me to understand why I have the full disk but in reality, it isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are using *logical volume management* (LVM)

- the `/dev/sda1` partition contains an LVM physical volume (PV)
- the PV is assigned to a volume group (VG)
- the VG contains your root filesystem

So

- the PV fully occupies the partition
- the filesystem fully occupies the VG

but

- the files only occupy a small fraction of the filesystem

Comment: So if i want to edit the partition, should i change the filesystem of the disk?

Comment: @Kvadrat see if this helps: [How to shrink Ubuntu LVM logical and physical volumes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252204/how-to-shrink-ubuntu-lvm-logical-and-physical-volumes)