# How to extend lvm partition on 1 hard drive

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I have ubuntu running to 447G ssd. However for some reason ubuntu only took 100G of that space on install (maybe I have missed something, does not matter now). How can I extend this partition to use all available space (preferably without data loss). Here is lsblk output:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop1                       7:1    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
loop2                       7:2    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop3                       7:3    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/858
loop4                       7:4    0  40.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19993
loop5                       7:5    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
sda                         8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 444.1G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
```

as you can see └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv only takes 100G, instead of 444 available.

Comment: Try: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733982/expanding-a-drive-partition-without-data-loss & https://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & https://askubuntu.com/questions/252204/how-to-shrink-ubuntu-lvm-logical-and-physical-volumes