# resize Ubuntu Partition to install windows alongside

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, gparted

[image]

I wanted to install ubuntu alongside windows but it formatted the disk completely, now I want to install windows alongside ubuntu, above is the link to present status of harddisk (gparted)

Please help me how to resize the partition and install windows, I am a complete newbie to linux/ubuntu as such.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume to resize lvm2-pv partition.

Comment: Thanks.. but the problem for me is its the same disk where ubuuntu is booted from and secondly the lvm partition is inside(sub-partition) of extended partition sda2

Comment: boot ubuntu live-cd and try the above link.

Comment: It doesn't work... bcoz most of the commands are giving errors that the disk is being used even after unmounting

Answer (score 0):

You have an tutorial here : http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/ , did you try ?

Be carreful, nou need boot to live CD/USB

Else, you can try this : [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)

Comment: Thanks.. but gparted does not shrink a lvm partition..i have already tried this step but to no avail..

Comment: Try this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume