# How to resize an encrypted LLVM volume and configure it to install another Linux distribution alongside Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, gparted

I chose to install Ubuntu with a fully encrypted disk, using LLVM.

How can I resize my partition so that I can install a new Linux version alongside Ubuntu?

Here's my current gparted status, this is the Ubuntu default:

[image: gparted - partition status]

I have already seen the following question:

- [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)

However, that is not about resizing an **encrypted partition**, but it only talks about the standard LLVM volume. Also, it does not talk about installing the OS after resizing partitions. Can I just use the same `/boot` partition? How do I configure this?

Comment: @simao: I don't have much knowledge about the topic at hand. But I can see that there are two things which you want to perform - (1) resize the encrypted LLVM volume and (2) install another linux distro... Is it possible to post separate questions for them? Or are they interlinked with each other and the way you resize depends upon the second question? So, if they can be separated, please [edit] to remove the second part from this question and post a new one for it.