# Merge two Partitions

Tags: partitioning

I want to merge two partitions in my ubuntu machine. But i don't want the files to be deleted in this process.

I have a 50gb ,formatted in ext 4 which i had installed my operating system and another one is 440 gb formatted in ext4.

Comment: I can not install new software because of low system space. can anybody help in this regard?

Comment: Do you want to add space for your 50 GB partition?

Comment: Actually I wanted to make a single partition as a whole but adding space to 50gb partition would also solve the problem. I don't have any unallocated space right now. Do i need to detele the 440gb partition?

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/2z7gbau.png

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume