# How can I resize an LVM partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, updates, gparted, lvm

I have problems with system update because my boot disk is too small, but I don't know how to increase this.

I have tried gparted live from a USB drive, but I can not reduce the size of the other partitions.  This is my partition table

gparted:
[image]

drives:
[image]

Comment: You have to unmount all partitios first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gparted does not manage LVM, you have to resize them manually with a live usb.

I suggest you first free up space on /boot , see [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

If that fails, [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)