# LVM - split logical volume

Tags: 14.04, lvm

I've just installed Ubuntu on a new machine and while I usually go for the classic partitioning, I decided to use (default) LVM this time as the idea of creating volume snapshots was quite appealing. (moreover, I chose whole system encryption)

However, after the default install I ended up with only 2 logical volumes (swap and root) and am unable to take snapshots. The first question therefore is:

**Q1: What is the point of such default LVM setup in Ubuntu?**

While the inability to take snapshots is probably easy to solve, it seems to me it would not be of much use unless I create another logical volumes (e.g. one for /home) as I don't want the snapshot to include files in /home folder. The second question then is:

**Q2: What is the good way of creating another logical volume, assigning it a mount point and moving files into it?**

Note #1: My user's home is encrypted as well.

Note #2: While I did find several tutorials regarding use of LVM, this topic is not covered in any of them.

Answer (score 1):

**STANDARD DISCLAIMER: I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. YOUR RESULTS MAY VARY. I AM NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY DATA LOSS YOU MAY INCUR. MAKE SURE YOU HAVE BACKUPS OF ANY CRITICAL DATA BEFORE ATTEMPTING THIS PROCEDURE.**

**Q.1:** You will need to leave some free space in your VG if you plan on snapshotting.

**Q.2:** You can create a new LV to use for */home* in the same VG. If you already allocated the entire disk to the *root* LV, you will need to resize it first to generate unallocated space for your new */home* LV (and space for snapshots if you plan on using that capability). You can do this from a live USB flash drive.

- Once booted from the live USB medium, you will need to manually
  unlock the LUKS container to access the LVs. (See *man cryptsetup*.)
- After you resize the *root* LV (See *man lvreduce*.) and create your 
  new */home* LV (See *man lvcreate*.), format your new */home* LV and
  then mount the two LVs at a temporary location in your live
  filesystem (such as */mnt/root* & */mnt/home*).
- You can then mirror your original */home* filesystem to the new
  */home* LV using *rsync* (from */mnt/root/home* to */mnt/home*).
- Update the fstab on the root LV to mount the new LV at */home*. Remove
  the contents of the original */home* folder (*sudo rm -rf
  /mnt/root/home/**), making sure to leave the empty folder as the mount
  point for your new */home* LV.
- You should then be able to reboot from the live USB into your
  installed system which will now have separate *root* and */home* LVs.

Further reading: [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)

Comment: +1 for the second answer. I'll give it a try. As for your first answer, I was rather interested why by default Ubuntu creates only 2 logical volumes without ability to take snapshots. It seems to me useless after default installation so I was curious if there is some deeper reasoning for this.