# Shrinking root using logical Volume Management

Tags: partitioning

Currently, Ubuntu 14.04 is my only OS. so, i decide to shrink my root to install windows 7. i use logical volume management but it says: 
"Logical volume is not mounted but is in use. Please close all applications using this device (eg iscsi)"

so, how can i solve this problem? or is there any better ways to shrink the root?

Comment: Do both OS exist on same hard disk? In that case you will have to boot from something else like a DVD or pen drive.

Comment: ubuntu is my only OS.. i want to shrink root to install windows7

Comment: You can't do that if the drive is currently in use, you will have to boot from some other device to shrink root.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look here. [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-phy%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bsical-volume)

You'll basically have to boot from a live CD, use system-config-lvm to shrink the logical volume and then use gparted to shrink the physical volume. Please pay attention to the details listed on that topic. You can ignore the commands if you're not experienced with the terminal.

Comment: hmm, with regular partitions you can use gparted, and on reboot it will resize.  Nothing like that for LVM?