# I have no space for upgrade. I was extended my disk and gparted it, but still no space for upgrade

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, gparted, disk

I have 10 GB Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on virtual disk in Virtual Box.

When I am trying upgrade, installer says me not enough space. I was enlarged disk image for 20 GB and Gparted partitions to whole new space. But still can´t upgrade and no space error:

[image: Not enough space]

[image: My partitions in Gparted]

[image: My partitions in Ubuntu X]

Comment: Plwase, if you answer your owne question, do it as a proper answer, not an edit to the question.

Comment: SOLVED:

I was solved this by this solution:

 1. (optional) Check how much space you've got left on your Volume Group
    with sudo vgdisplay
 2. Find the name of your Logical Volume with sudo lvdisplay
 3. Extend the volume by 5GB: sudo lvextend -L+5GB /dev/ssd/sysLV
 4. Increase the filesystem size to match the LV: sudo resize2fs
    /dev/ssd/sysLV (ext4 only, see this link for other filesystems)
 5. df -h should now report the correct size.

from this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/580460/logical-volume-is-not-mounted-but-is-in-use-please-close-all-applications-using