# Can I resize a physical volume?

Tags: 12.04, lvm, mint

I've been trying to solve the following problem 5 good hours now. I've recently installed Linux Mint 17 with LVM, erasing my hard disk. For some reason I want to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 alongside my previous installation, without losing any data, but LVM is not supported by 12.04 and now I'm stuck. I've managed to resize the logical volume to free up some space, but this is hopeless anyway, because I cannot resize the physical partition to free some space for a new installation.

Is it possible to resize the physical partition? Some people say yes, some people say no and I'm quite lost in it because I'm an inexperienced linux user.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Guess this link can help you `http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume`

Comment: I've already read that topic, but I haven't managed to do anything with it. I'm actually unable to use the "accepted" answer to solve my problem as I don't know how to apply it to my case. When I open system-config-lvm, I see mint-vg as a volume group and then a physical partition /dev/sda5 and two logical views /dev/mint-vg/swap_1 and /dev/mint-vg/root. What should I substitute vg_blah and lv_blah with? Also, the physical volume has its data arranged in the following order: root, unused space and swap_1. Should I delete swap_1 to complete the steps listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at **pvresize** yet? If you're LV doesn't span all your available PEs then you can just reduce it. Otherwise you have to shrink everything like Vembu proposed and the resize the pv.

**This is extremely high risk and you can easily lose everything so back up first**

Comment: OK, I managed to do everything correctly now, I didn't delete the swap space and this wouldn't let me finish the process. So I have freed enough space for the second linux installation. Does the mount point for the second distribution have to be specific? Could I just use / and be OK? I'm sorry about the many question, I'm just a bit afraid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mount point. You're supposed to be creating a new partition and installing the distro to that. Of course that distro's / needs to point to the new partition created, or you're going to scribble all over your other distro.

If you're not absolutely sure you're doing this right, do not proceed.

Comment: All good, I've finished the job.