# Unable to resize deactivated partition in Gparted from LiveUSB

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 but would like to dual boot Windows. I am trying to resize my Ubuntu partition and create a new partition from Windows. I am doing this by booting from an Ubuntu 14.04 LiveUSB and running GParted. However, after "deactivating the partition" (I thought I was supposed to unmount...), GParted only lets me reduce my main partition size by 15 MiB. Here is an image of my GParted window from the LiveUSB, after deactivating /dev/sda3.

[image]

**How can I manage to resize my main /dev/sda3/ partition?**

Comment: it is lvm, gparted will not resize lvm. try the gparted live cd or system-config-lvm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)