# Unable to resize lvm2 partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gparted, lvm

I have been facing this issue even when I boot through Gparted LiveCD. My goal is to install Windows dual booting with Ubuntu (My wife is not comfortable with linux)

Don't ask me about the ext2 and fat32 partitions here, I don't have any clue myself as to when and how they got created. Also let me know if it would be safe to remove these.

Suggestions? Advice?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Look at http://askubuntu.com/q/196125/350004

Comment: You can not resize with gparted. Also, LVM fragments the data and there is no defragmenter. It is designed to be able to enlarge, but data loss can happen when you downsize. If you have data loss, the data is not over written, just reverse the process. In that event you need to back up your data and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks Sharad for being a proactive reader @SharadGautam
Any idea what those other partitions are, should I remove them?

Comment: `sda1` is the [ESP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and you need it to boot in EFI+GPT. `sda2` is certainly a boot partition and hold your kernel, and yes you need it.

Comment: Follow solsTiCe's link and advice. Also, your computer is booting in EFI/UEFI mode. After you've resized your LVM, you must install Windows in the same mode, as described [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/186875-uefi-unified-extensible-firmware-interface-install-windows-7-a.html) (among other places). You may then need to use the firmware's built-in boot manager to reboot to Ubuntu and then run `sudo update-grub` to get GRUB to recognize Windows.

Comment: @solsTiCe Add it as an answer.

Comment: There is nice GUI package in the Software Center called KVPM.  It is the easiest method for managing LVM, for physical volume (PV) and logical volumes (lv).  But, you will need to run the program from a liveUSB, since you can't re-size a mounted volume.

Answer (score 0):

`sda1` is the **[ESP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)** and you need it to boot in EFI+GPT. `sda2` is certainly a **boot** partition and hold your *kernel*, and yes you need it.

LVM is tricky to shrink. Look at the previous ansver there: [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/q/196125/350004)