# Add a swap partition post-install 15.04

Tags: 15.04, swap

I installed 15.04 onto a lvm partition with the mount point / and /boot onto a separate unencrypted partition.

Can someone list the steps (clearly please) to set up a swap partition post-install? It would be helpful also to see the steps for both an encrypted swap and non-encrypted swap.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to shrink the LVM volume

Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume) to learn how. you can either use the answer marked or use gparted with version > 0.14.

One you shrink the LVM you can know create a new partition for swap using Gparted.

Now it's time to add this newly create parition to fstab

You need to edit /etc/fstab and add the new swap partition.

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

You need to add a line that looks like

```
UUID=new-partition-UUID none   swap    sw      0       0
```

You can get the UUID using the command

```
sudo blkid /dev/sdaX
```

Where sdaX stands for the newly created partition

---

---

**Another workaround is to create a swap file instead of a swap partition.**

in this i'm going to create a 4G swap file

```
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
```

verify that the correct amount of space was reserved by typing:

```
ls -lh /swapfile
```

output should be

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0G Apr 28 13:19 /swapfile
```

To enable the swap file:

```
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
```

Verify that the file has the correct permissions:

```
ls -lh /swapfile
```

output should be:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 4.0G Apr 28 17:19 /swapfile
```

Now teell  system to set up the swap space:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

output would be like:

```
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 4194300 KiB no label, UUID=e2f1e9cf-c0a9-4ed4-b8ab-714b8a7d6944
```

Our file is now ready to be used as a swap space. We can enable this by typing:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

We can verify that the procedure was successful by checking whether our system reports swap space now:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

output would be like:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        4194300 0       -1
```

[source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: blkid shows me this: /dev/sda6: UUID="e2342vda-c324-2434-324c-84723ff298c" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="98274938-4e32-4etf-9e32-0938g8342"   How do I add this into the fstab properly?

Comment: `UUID=e2342vda-c324-2434-324c-84723ff298c none   swap    sw      0       0`

Comment: By simply adding this line into fstab, when I boot ubuntu, enter my drive encrypt passphrase and login, will it recognize the encrypted swap partition as such? I assume once I login I will need to unlock the swap partition.

Comment: I assume that the next step is to tell the system to use this swap?

Comment: How about: sudo swapon  ?

Comment: using: sudo swapon -a

I receive the following message: swapon: /dev/sda6: read swap header failed

Comment: How do I make the swapfile permanent? It forgets the swapfile after a while. Not sure if that's after a reboot or after installing a system update that replaced the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem and worked to setup unencrypted swap but I just want to clarify the steps I took.

1. In gparted - formated a partition as the type - linuxswap
2. In terminal I ran "sudo blkid /dev/sdaX" to copy the UUID of the swap partition.
3. I edited /etc/fstab and add the new swap partition by adding the line UUID=new-partition-UUID none   swap    sw      0       0
4. ran "sudo swapon & sudo swapon -a & sudo swapon -s"
5. rebooted the computer and voila! - verified using ActivityMonitor

Now the question remains, how does one encrypt the swap drive?