# How do I unock my LVM Partition so I can resize /boot?

Tags: boot, partitioning, lvm

So I have 2 partitions, one of which is /boot and the other is everything else in an LVM logical volume.  Problem is I'm getting warnings about how much space is on /boot. Warnings are increasingly frequent so I figured I better resize. I made a boot disk, specifically gparted live with tuxboot. It works fine but I can't get the volume to resize.  I can see the logical volume and I can deactivate it but this does not seem to allow any resizing.  I note the logical partition is yellow and the boot partition is only partly yellow. Does this mean it's full? ...because it's not. Clues??

Thanks

Comment: You would probably be better off removing old kernel versions to free space on /boot.  Try running `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`

Comment: I think your question has already been answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume).

Comment: @user4901968 Already been there but thanks. :-)