# How to add unused space

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk, disk-usage, disk-management

my machine has a lot of unused space. Here is the output from the command `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`

```
NAME                          FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                                          80G
├─sda1                        ext2          243M /boot
├─sda2                                        1K
└─sda5                        LVM2_member  19.8G
  ├─dist--3--vg-root (dm-0)   ext4         15.8G /
  └─dist--3--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) swap            4G [SWAP]
sr0                                        1024M
```

However, my system only recognizes around 30GB:

```
ubuntu@slave-2:~$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/dist--3--vg-root   16G  9.8G  4.8G  68% /
none                          4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                          3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                         799M  732K  798M   1% /run
none                          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                          3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /run/shm
none                          100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                     236M  227M     0 100% /boot
cm_processes                  3.9G  316K  3.9G   1% /run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
```

Now how can I add the unused partition to the normal partition. I don't have access to GUI, only via Terminal.

Comment: post output of `df -hT` - I need to see the type of filesystem on `/dev/sda2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)