# How to increase my /boot partition size in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot

I am trying to increase by /boot as it has reduced the capacity to install new updates. The partition details are given below:

[image]

Please suggest me a way to increase the /boot partition to atleast 1GB

Comment: Is this an LVM install? IF so gparted will not work. If not LVM then probably better to not have /boot partition. How to resize LVM:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Comment: 480 MB should be more than enough for a boot partition. You may want to [remove some old kernel packages](/q/2793/175814). Otherwise this question is a duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](/q/126153/175814)

Answer (score 3):

It is Better To use live GParted USB because it is best when the system is not running an OS. And plug the USB first into the ubuntu system for making Live USB

1. Download GParted live USB iso size nearly equal to 300 MBs [Iso For 64 bit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.26.1-1/gparted-live-0.26.1-1-amd64.iso/download) and [ISO for 32 bit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.26.1-1/gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso/download).
2. press windows key or Launch the Startup Disk Creator from the application menu/Dash [image: Startup Disk Creator]

or run the following command in the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t):

`usb-creator-gtk`

3. Select the source CD/Image, click 'Other...' to browse for the file.
   [image]
4. Select Iso image.
5. Click Make Startup Disk and wait.
6. Reboot the system and Press the key which lets you select the boot device.
7. Select Your USB Drive And then gpated will start.
8. Shrink your 3rd partition and then merge the unallocated space into your /boot.
9. It takes some time and don't forget to keep laptop on charging incase it takes longer time and if battery runs out your data can get corrupt.
   Hope It solved your problem.

Further Details [GPARTED MANUAL](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using gparted from a live USB. The process can take a lot of time to complete if your partitions are big. However, if you have a partition after the boot partition, it could not be resized unless you move or resize the other partitions, but most of the times, the resize procedure is easy and efective. Be careful!, make a backup of your data before proceed, a bad move can cause a potential data loss.

To run gparted from the live usb, if it is not installed, install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

For more information look at:

[Gparted Manual: Resize partition](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gparted to resize partitions in Ubuntu or any of its derivatives. Usually gparted is installed by default. Run `sudo gparted` in a terminal to start gparted. If it returns with an error stating gparted not found or something similar it is then not installed in your system. Run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted to install gparted.

Details about using gparted can be found on their website i.e. [www.gparted.org](http://www.gparted.org)