# Dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 + 16.04 setup?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 16.04 64b Desktop installed on a HP Touchsmart (with LVM); associated with I that spent quite some time setting up an unusual application with it.  Now I need to run another different application but it will not install & run properly on 16.04, instead requires 14.04 (per its vendor).

So...I went to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop expecting to set up a dual-boot configuration during the installation, but the 14.04 Desktop installer (running from DVD) reports back that it does not detect any existing OS installed already, and wants to wipe my HDD data.  I do NOT want to wipe out my existing 16.04 installation with my primary app for that, as it was too much time/trouble to get everything working right.

How can I accomplish this dual boot with existing 16.04 and adding 14.04?  (I haven't found a searchable answer, as all the other dual-boot Q&A seems to deal with an existing Windows OS.)

Answer (score 1):

Press super key
Enter Gparted
Select it
Select any big ext4 disk right click>unmount again right click>resize partition....reduce some space and make around 70 to 80 gb space which is unallocated.. apply settings make bootable pendrive of Ubuntu 14.04 and follow this..
Boot ur pendrive 
And select install ubuntu and then...
(Images are of 16.04 doesn't matter and here free space is 150 u can allocate accordingly)
[image: i will prefer install alongside if u wish to do it manually do these]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Neglect along side windows option this is not your case. select something else
Continue installation...reboot after completion.. hope this helps :)

Edit :FOR LVM RESIZING
REFER TO [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)

Comment: Check which system (legacy or UEFI) ur previous Ubuntu is installed in... accordingly boot your pendrive

Comment: My system is not a UEFI BIOS system.  Furthermore, the BIOS does not provide an option to boot from USB, only removable bootable source is DVD; thus I am trying to install OS from DVD.

Comment: I had a problem right away out of the starting gate:  there appears to be no Gparted on the installed 16.04 LTS Desktop (64b).  Could there be another partition editor under a different name in this OS?

Comment: U can manually install gparted> sudo apt-get install gparted

Comment: After entering that apt-get command (and after supplying password) I get an error message: "E: Invalid operation gparted".

Comment: BTW, when searching for gparted on the machine, it finds only a PNG file (icon) for it...implies that it exists somewhere, but whereis reports nothing.

Comment: This is really weird :/ google for how to install gparted

Comment: SORRY: I failed to enter the complete sudo command (left out the "install").  Successfully installed gparted, now will try to resize etc.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you described in gparted (no unmount, and resize dialog shows min & max sizes are identical, and larger than what it presently it).  The entire LVM volume group and volume /dev/sda ("ubuntu-vg/root"), along with Swap ("ubuntu-vg/swap-1") is shown as "free space" and "unallocated" in the Disks utility app.  Ie, gparted is not enabling me to change the size of that volume.  I fired up lvm on CLI, but am nervous about correct way to run lvmresize in a manner that does not destroy the existing ext4 file system and data (only about 5% of the space is used in that volume).

Comment: U can't edit partition unless u unmount them..its been a long time i deal with it...plz find a option to unmount..

Comment: But it seems that u r doing lot more complex stuffs installing same ubuntu alongside updated version...i suggest u remove everything using softwares like minitool partition wizard delete every disk and start from scratch and install a single ubuntu 14.04 iso... won't it be better for stability and performance both?

Comment: I went through too many days of getting the existing Ubuntu 16.04 and GNS3 app configured to play together to risk repeating that process, thus why I'm trying to get this dual-boot to work...even though it looks like it's going to take as much time to do this 14.04 dual boot install ;-(

Comment: I'm researching LVM resizing now (making sure I have the CLI command right so as not to delete existing valuable data), so that I can free up space on the HDD to partition separately.  Will report back on that.

Comment: As far i remember... ubuntu automatically detects of LVM type on the first screen of installation...i dont know whats wrong in your case

Comment: I found your resizing LVM edit/commend useful, THX!  Used the GUI LVM tool, LVM CLI, and parted to to safely reduce the volume group to half the physical size of the drive, and then reduced the physical disc size assigned to that LV group half to match.  Also moved the swap file from the end of the physical disc to the beginning of the volume group, thus leaving the rest of the physical disc as free unallocated and unformatted space, which is not assigned to /dev/sda6.   See photo of screen shot for that.

Comment: hmmm...can't seem to find a way to insert or attach the screen shot photo here.

Comment: Anyway, now I'm back at the liveDVD of Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 to install it alongside the existing Ubuntu 16.04 installation.  However, the install still does NOT detect an existing OS installed (the Ubuntu 16.04).  I'm nervous about proceeding with the install as it sure looks to me that if Ubuntu had not detected the previous existing Ubuntu that it will surely overwrite everything.

Comment: Ya u will have to do something else option...there is no option like install ubuntu alongside other ubuntu...backup your imp data ij case of failure

Comment: If this solution solved ur problem..plz tick √ and mark the thread as solved

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45759/discussion-on-answer-by-sardapv-dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-16-04-setup).