# How can I decrease size of my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning

When I installed Ubuntu on my system my hard formatted entirely and Ubuntu installed on it. Now i want to change partitions of hard disk but it seems is impossible.

[image]

How can I resize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to boot from another media for doing something like this, you can't (at least without a HUGE chance to screw up everithing) change the partition without unmount it, and unmount the system partition and continuing using the system isn't a easy task.

For doing what you are asking, is better to boot from a live cd and change the partition from it. The  Ubuntu trial have gparted available, and from it you can resize your partition.

Remember that if you install something (read windows operating systems) that isn't grub aware, your installation will cover grub, and you will not be able to boot from Ubuntu without reinstalling grub. The same can happen if you *move* the partition instead of only resizing it.

EDIT: I noticed that OP was using lvm, and so gparted only will not do what it needs.

See [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-system-config-lvm.html) for a tutorial on resizing with *system-config-lvm*.

Comment: sorry, i didn't saw the image with the partitions, you are using lvm... to edit that, use system-config-lvm

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume) (i can't post comments on questions because of my reputation, so i'm posting here)