# How can I extend my Boot partition?

Tags: boot, gparted, partitioning

Is it possible to extend my boot partition without having to format the whole disk? Here is what my configuration looks like:

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

No. That is you cannot easily expand your `/dev/sda1` partition.

You could probably free up space on `/dev/sda1` with the `purge-old-kernels` script (see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/purge-old-kernels.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using LVM, your ability to grow non-LVM partitions is limited. See [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume) for information on how to do it if it really is vital that you do so.