# Resize a partition that is using LVM

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I have a laptop that is currently running ParrotOS Security. The root partition is about 460G and I want to split it so I can dual-boot Ubuntu. However, when I try to resize the partition using the instructions from [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume) using the live version of Ubuntu, I get an error when I run e2fsck that says something along the lines of `the selected parition is using an unknown meta-chsum, upgrade your e2fsck!` I just downloaded the ISO from Ubuntu yesterday so I know it's an updated version. It's loaded on a bootable USB so I should be able to perform package upgrades, however when I try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade util-linux` I get an error that says `dpkg exited with error code 1`
Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: The exact error that I get when attempting to run `e2fsck /dev/blah` is

```
/dev/blah has unsupported feature(s): metadata_csum
e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!
```

I get the same error when trying edit using `system-config-lvm`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)

Comment: @AndroidDev I referenced that post in my question. I run into trouble when attempting that solution.

Comment: Did you try the second tool that references using `system-config-lvm` as well then?

Comment: This might or might not obviate the problem, but it is possible to share an LVM volume group between multiple distributions; you'd need nothing but a small `/boot` partition outside of the LVM for each distribution. If you have sufficient free space outside of the LVM (~500 MiB) for a new Ubuntu `/boot` partition, then this may be the way to go.

Comment: @RodSmith thanks for the thought, but unfortunately the only unallocated space available on the disk is a little over 1 MiB.