# GParted won't seem to let me shrink an encrypted partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, gparted

I have a 1TB (or thereabouts) SSD drive on my laptop, on which is installed Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to increase the size of the boot partition, so I've booted from a live CD, and ran GParted.

I have two partitions - the main one, `/dev/sda2`, and the boot one, `/dev/sda1`.  Within `/dev/sda2` is an **encrypted partition** called `/dev/sda5`.  It looks like this:

[image]

I can right click on `/dev/sda2`, and choose "Resize/Move", but on the following dialog it doesn't let me make any changes.

Is this because I would need to shrink the encrypted partition within `/dev/sda2` first, and you can't resize encrypted partitions?  That seems plausible but my knowledge runs out at this point.

Comment: See also: [Unix & Linux: How to edit/resize an LVM partition graphically (with a GUI)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/583639/114401)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partition`/dev/sda2` is an extended partition under which the logical partition `/dev/sda5` was created. Although this would not have been necessary for the setup being shown in the screenshot you've provided, the reason to create an extended partition is to achieve the possibility to create more than three additional partitions later on. It is not possible to create more than four primary partitions on a disk with msdos (MBR) partition table. But now to your question : you can - and have to - resize the partition `/dev/sda5`. First decrypt this partition and then start the resizing process with GParted ...

- Shrink `/dev/sda5` (make all free space to be preceding space)
- Shrink `/dev/sda2` (make all free space to be preceding space)
- Grow `/dev/sda1` (**add the complete free unallocated space**)

It is important that afterwards no free unallocated space is left between `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`,
which means that you may need to add 1 MB still remaining space to `/dev/sda1` or to `/dev/sda2`.
I've tested it in a virtual machine, but I recommend to [backup the disk](http://clonezilla.org) in case something goes wrong.
Find more information about partition resizing and what you have to pay attention to : [GParted Manual](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-resize-partition)

Comment: Hi Max, what I wrote was the answer addressing your question, but what I recommend is something different. Ubuntu 14.04 is nearing EOL and the whole setup is not "the most professional one". So, I would backup the personal data and then start over from scratch - first create a new partition table, then create a new partition, format it with ext4 and then install Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS ... adjust your individual configuration from within the Ubuntu installer. Once the installation process has finished, boot the system and restore back your data. :)

Comment: Thanks @cl-netbox but I actually want to stick with 14.04 to replicate our work server environment.  WRT your answer, can I decrypt it in place?  Or would I need to decrypt it to another HDD, say?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes, you can decrypt the partition "in place", there is no need to move something. After having tested the resizing process in a virtual machine, I updated the answer with the relevant steps. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Following this answer, and using Gparted Live, I unlock and try to shrink the lvm2 partition (called sda5 for me), but the resize dialog doesn't allow me to adjust the settings in it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @BPugh You may want to read [How can I resize a LVM partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume) ... :)

Comment: How do I decrypt the partition within `Gparted`? Actually, my encrypted partition is the one I'm working on. Seems like I'd have to flash a USB to be able to change its size then, since it can't be mounted while being modified anyway, isn't it so?

Comment: Exactly @AndreasL. ! You can't modify mounted system partitions ... boot from a GParted USB drive. :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a much easier solution. Run Xubuntu live, install and launch partitionmanager. It can very well handle encrypted partitions.

Complete details are here: http://e1z.ca/devlog/encrypted_partition_resize.html

Comment: Ah, sounds promising.  I will investigate when my in-tray stops being on fire - thanks!

Comment: Except that there is no 'decrypt' option in partitionmanager now. I just installed it from a Mint 20.2 live usb, and a right-click on my encrypted partition shows no decrypt option. Is there something special has to be done beyond running it sudo?

Comment: The URL is broken. :(

Comment: The instructions were simple. Install Xubuntu live on a pendrive. Boot your system from the pen drive. You will have the option to install & launch partitionmanager. The simple point to notice is that you wont be able to rezise encrypted partion if Linux is booted from the same partition. All you need is an external system and any standard partitioning manager should be able to resize the disks.

Answer (score 0):

> GParted won't seem to let me shrink an encrypted partition

I had the same problem as just this *title* of the question implies.

My problem was that GParted does *not* allow you shrink an outer LUKS-encrypted partition until *first* the inner LVM volumes within it are shrunk! To do that, you have to use **Gnome Disks** to unlock the outer LUKS-encrypted partition, and then **`blivet-gui`** to shrink the inner LVM volumes within it. Once that is done, you go to **GParted** and shrink the outer LUKS-encrypted partition. All 3 tools are required.

See my detailed instructions and screenshots here. It took me quite a bit of time to figure this out: [Unix & Linux: Unlock a LUKS-encrypted outer partition, shrink and edit the LVM volume(s) within it, and then shrink the outer LUKS partition using a combination of 3 GUIs: Gnome "Disks", "blivet-gui", and "GParted"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728750/114401).