# Not able to build Docker image (write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob997861703: no space left on device)

Tags: disk-usage, docker

trying to pull a docker image, not able to figure it out

Step 1: I deleted all the older Docker images.

```
[pinn@dat src]$ sudo docker images
[sudo] password for pinn: 
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

Step 2:

```
[pinn@dat src]$ sudo docker pull dnanexus/parliament2:hgsc 
Trying to pull repository docker.io/dnanexus/parliament2 ... 
hgsc: Pulling from docker.io/dnanexus/parliament2
99ad4e3ced4d: Pulling fs layer 
ec5a723f4e2a: Pulling fs layer 
2a175e11567c: Pulling fs layer 
8d26426e95e0: Pulling fs layer 
46e451596b7c: Waiting 
c63048c591c5: Waiting 
6dab66ad6a6b: Waiting 
073018493d1a: Waiting 
d9093f8394cf: Waiting 
39e408d30bae: Pulling fs layer 
8f3d038bef6f: Waiting 
9408994aa68f: Waiting 
2ebbf92a58f2: Waiting 
216048caddf1: Waiting 
512150e718ce: Waiting 
579c94bc81a0: Waiting 
544e55a379f1: Waiting 
76e4dd1249e2: Waiting 
b09afdc7bfbc: Pulling fs layer 
6dcc5772958e: Waiting 
c60523b7d808: Waiting 
512150e718ce: Downloading [==================================================>]   602 MB/602 MB
0a8d29044929: Downloading [==================================================>]   507 MB/507 MB
7b5bc22a6b0f: Downloading [==================================================>] 14.99 MB/14.99 MB
08000760e6cd: Download complete 
c032a1aa4aca: Download complete 
fe7145687289: Download complete 
22233c8f0e35: Download complete 
7c2915c43556: Download complete 
80c5a9e21000: Downloading [==================================================>] 491.3 MB/491.3 MB
b51941c9c78e: Downloading [==================================================>] 491.3 MB/491.3 MB
d4be8cb6829d: Download complete 
4a01224d389b: Download complete 
9109511ef564: Download complete 
b18603b9bf45: Download complete 
22e1f71498ed: Download complete 
024be5d16e13: Download complete 
040573916ee9: Download complete 
c803bf724b83: Download complete 
823cb891a20c: Download complete 
7d0b35ba0798: Download complete 
c7f65657d722: Download complete 
95d76f17846a: Download complete 
42e613c0c2f1: Download complete 
**write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob997861703: no space left on device**
```

Results of `df -h`

```
[pinn@dat src]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  197G   78G  110G  42% /
devtmpfs                 504G     0  504G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    504G   52K  504G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    504G  494M  504G   1% /run
tmpfs                    504G     0  504G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                2.0G  324M  1.7G  16% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home  765G  506G  220G  70% /home
/dev/mapper/centos-var   9.8G  9.2G   39M 100% /var
/dev/sdb                  82T   73T  5.3T  94% /data
tmpfs                    101G   52K  101G   1% /run/user/0
tmpfs                    101G     0  101G   0% /run/user/1009
tmpfs                    101G     0  101G   0% /run/user/1004
tmpfs                    101G     0  101G   0% /run/user/1002
tmpfs                    101G     0  101G   0% /run/user/1006
tmpfs                    101G     0  101G   0% /run/user/1013
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker's operational data is in `/var` by default.  This includes all containers and images, networking, temporary build layers, and objects it's transforming (for example when exporting or importing).

According to your `df -h` output:

/dev/mapper/centos-var   9.8G  9.2G   39M 100% /var

Being as that is a mapped partition (probably LVM?)  you should be able to change its size to be more appropriate to your needs.

Comment: How to change its size ?

Comment: To resize partitions you can use `gnome-disks` or `gparted` or use any of the answers in this question for LVM (presuming it is LVM): https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume