# Why GPARTED showing different partition size than the "df" command?

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to shrink this /dev/mapper partition, which says has 71 GB available space:

```
    Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                  2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                 413M  656k  412M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg-root                   133G   56G   71G  45% /
tmpfs                                 2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                 5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                 2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                             495M  494M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs                                 413M     0  413M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I boot my machine (Ubuntu 18.04 Server) using GPARTED Live CD. But when I open GPARTED, it only says [see image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppV3e.png) 48 MB is available. It's showing as unmount, but I can't shrink the volume to more than 48 MB. Any ideas why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw this post earlier but what I'm probably confused is why GPARTED gives a different results if compared to the "df" command.

Comment: BTW, in your image of `gparted` the key means that the partition is mounted so you cannot shrink it at that time.

Comment: Maybe also see:  https://superuser.com/questions/917988/gparted-cannot-resize-extended-or-lvm-partition

Comment: Will check this link. I believe it's already unmounted, since the "Resize" option is there.

Comment: `gparted` may also not be able to actually resize a LVM to smaller because it is reading it there as a whole partition and not looking into the LVM.