# How to use remaining 1.8T?

Tags: partitioning

I just built my new server and realized that I accidentally only allotted 200GB to Ubuntu leaving the remaining 1.8TB unusable on my server. I have already tried partitioning using sudo to resize the partition, but I got an error saying that the resource was busy. I attached a screenshot for reference. I also am only using a terminal so no GUI solutions will work.

Results of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`:

[image]

Comment: Since you're using a logical volume, it shouldn't be too difficult to change the size from 200GB to 2TB (if that's your goal). [This answer from a few years ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/489909/1091774) should give you everything you need to manage the volume 

Comment: Please open a terminal and enter `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` commands. Add the output to your question (please add formatted text, not image), so you could be helped with detailed instructions.