# home directory is full even tho the home partition is not

Tags: partitioning, encryption, gparted, home-directory

I have recently increased my home partition's size using GParted, from ~10GB to 150GB.

lsblk outputs the following

```
sda                                             8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   529M  0 part  
├─sda2                                          8:2    0   100M  0 part  
├─sda3                                          8:3    0    16M  0 part  
├─sda4                                          8:4    0 146.6G  0 part  
├─sda5                                          8:5    0   512M  0 part  /boot
├─sda6                                          8:6    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda7                                          8:7    0    75G  0 part  
│ └─luks-bbdbcdd7-5c5a-4788-b469-7703c12a8f9f 253:0    0    75G  0 crypt /
└─sda8                                          8:8    0     8G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb                                             8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                                          8:17   0 781.5G  0 part  
└─sdb3                                          8:19   0   150G  0 part  
  └─luks-49d0b244-437c-4121-a5a7-8297611f7df1 253:1    0   150G  0 crypt /home
zram0                                         252:0    0     8G  0 disk  [SWAP]
```

However [disk usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lixsr.png) only shows the initial ~10GB size (pre-resize)

Hope someone knows what the problem is, haven't found a solution anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did GParted report success on "grow file system to fill partition" after expanding the partition?  BTW, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu -- please be sure to take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ] to better understand how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: @ZeissIkon yes, this was not the first time I've extended a partition, but it was the first time it went wrong. Thanks, I'll read it.

Comment: You are using LVM. So multiple commands required. https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Comment: @oldfred GParted is supposed to work with LVM... I might just abandon encryption and start over, too much trouble...