# Resize partition

Tags: server, partitioning

I just resized my vdisk to 128G. How can i resize the ubuntu main partition to 128G?
Its a virtual machine Ubuntu

```
    NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0   64G  0 disk /var/www/html
sr0                        11:0    1  1.1G  0 rom
vda                       252:0    0  128G  0 disk
├─vda1                    252:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─vda2                    252:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0 30.5G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   20G  0 lvm  /
```

Comment: If your partition is encrypted, then there may not be any easy way to do it. If not see [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume). You may have to do all these after booting from an ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my System to another with a higher disk size.