# Resize Ubuntu lvm2 pv partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I'm trying to resize the Ubuntu partition, but gparted or any live Ubuntu disck are not allowing me to do it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsR6a.png)

How can I reduce the ubuntu partition to 100GB?

Thank you

Comment: You need to use lvm tools, not Gparted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)

Comment: @ChanganAuto is there a guide where is explained how to resize an LVM partition with lvm tools?

Comment: @karel I tried but I don't understa what I've to put instead of "vg_bla" and "lv_blah" :D