# why is default installation of ubuntu 22.04 lts use half of available storage?

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, lvm

new installation of ubuntu 22.04 always try to use half of the available storage on the disk

how can we change this annoying default behavior, so it can use the full storage on disk?!?

[image]

Comment: I do not use LVM, but that is a feature. It allows you to either add more volumes or resize as desired. LVs can be thought of as easy-to-resize partitions. Shrinking is more difficult. http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm See resizing. two quick commands.

Comment: i know what LVM is but my question is why is default not using my whole current available disk size and how do i make it do so.

Comment: Answer already given by oldfred: shrinking is more difficult, so assigning the whole disk by default, you will be very likely to cause difficulties for user wanting to decrease, whereas this way, users that want to increase can do easily.

Comment: @vanadium i can always add more disks and extend like that again i WANT to use whole disk, i mean i can do this after install but i WANT to do it now during installation. What is so difficult in understanding what am asking?

Comment: Your question was "why is this the default". Please edit the title of your question if you actually want to know how to change the default. The title not reflecting the question is the difficulty in understanding what you are asking.