# How to resize lvm partition so I can give more space to /boot partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I have tried **gparted live**, so partitions are not mounted, but I cannot apply any change in main partition (because it's lvm partition I am afraid)

This are the details

```
Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 976771071 976269314 465.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 976771071 976269312 465.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

What I want is to give some extra space to /dev/sda1

Comment: I have tried, but lvreduce didn't work

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed, [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume) had the answer

My problem was I was running that commands indicating devices in my question (such as **/dev/sda5**), while that commands expected to indicate VG & LV names, which you can see by running **lvdisplay** command

Comment: Keep in mind that if the proposed duplicate had the answer, the normal course of action is to click the button in the header that says, (something like), "This answered my question.".  Thanks!

Comment: I know. Not here but I am an experienced user in other stack exchange websites. I consider my answer could be relevant to low level Unix users, so I think it could be useful to keep it