# Resize/Reduce ubuntu server partition size

Tags: partitioning

The following is the output of lsblk. sda3 size is 1.6TB and only 100GB is assigned to ubuntu-vg.

```
sda                         8:0    0   1.6T  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   1.6T  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
```

I want to reduce the size of /dev/sda3 to 500G
and create and new partition lets say sda4 from the freed space.

What's the right way to do it without losing data?

I would like the result as follows:

```
    sda                         8:0    0   1.6T  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   500G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
|sda4                       8:3    0   1.1T  0 part
```

Comment: I have ubuntu server with no GUI, so I can't use gparted. I want a solution without shutting down the system if possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)

Comment: @dreamxps Even if you don't shut down the system, you would need to stop all services running on the system, which would be the same effect. Not shutting down the system is possible by creating a minimal copy of Ubuntu inside a tmpfs and doing `systemctl switch-root` to it, but it is expert-level difficulty